# merging two dictionaries

Tags: iphone, merge, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am looking to merge dictionaries in response to the user requesting more data from a server call.

I see this method is one available to me:

```
- (void)addEntriesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)otherDictionary
```

Which states this:

> If both dictionaries contain the same key, the receiving dictionary’s
>   previous value object for that key is sent a release message, and the
>   new value object takes its place.

However for example on the first call my dictionary will have the keys 0, 1, 2, 3 as strings. Dont ask why this is the data I have to work with!

Then on another call for say the next 4 entries rather than getting string keys 4, 5, 6, 7 I get....0, 1, 2, 3!

So if I use the method above the original entries will always be overwritten.

Is there a way to merge such data so I get 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 etc?

Am I looking at some ugly form of enumeration?

Comment: Keys must be unique, I don't know what you want it to do.

Comment: thats the whole point of the problem!  I am limited by the incoming data...

Comment: What is the behavior that you would like to achieve? if you want to keep the old data and toss the old, then call addEntriesFromDictionary: on the newDictionary and overwrite the new data.

Comment: dude....have you even read my original post?  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If all of your keys are sequential integers, you should be using arrays instead (or convert to them if you can't change the source format). `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` will join them together after conversion, or `addObjectsFromArray:` if mutable.

Comment: I guess I should have expanded a little.  The incoming data in JSON that gives me a dictionary that contains something like 10 entries but each dictionary takes the returned value 0, 1, 2 etc so my dictionary starts out with keys 0, 1, 2 etc.  on subsequent calls although I call for the next say 4 items in the data it is returned in JSON that gives me keys 0, 1, 2 etc so I need to add these to the end of the first data received...but they have the same keys ergo the problem

Comment: Could you add what the incoming JSON looks like in your question, as well as what you want it to end up looking like?

Comment: {"0":{....},"1":{....},"2":{...}  so the digits are the dictionary keys and contained in each dictionary are strings etc.  For each call the JSON returns data with a dictionary always starting at zero.  Therefore as I already have keys with these values I need to merge/append the new JSON dictionary onto the end

Comment: turns out the folk creating the JSON have not formatted it correctly which they are now addressing, thus removing the need to fudge keys...Thanks for the responses guys